# How to access attributes of an element inside a group?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm not sure if I've grouped my elements properly, but my layout in d3 is like so:

```
var circleGroup = svg.selectAll("g")
               .data(nodeList)
               .enter()
               .append("g")
```

This creates a bunch a groups, I need a circle in each group:

```
circleGroup.append("circle") 
         .attr("cx", function(d,i){
            return coordinates[i][0];
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d,i){
            return coordinates[i][1];
         })
         .attr("r", function(d){
            return 10;
         })
         .attr("fill", "white");
```

The data itself doesn't actually have any coordinate data so I dynamically arrange them in a circle and just position them based on index. I also add some labels. I repeat coordinates[i][0] here but is there a way to access the "cx" and "cy" attributes of the circles? I tried a few forms of d3.select(this) but I'm getting nothing.

```
circleGroup.append("text")
         .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return coordinates[i][0];
         })
         .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return coordinates[i][1];
         })
         .style("text-anchor","middle")
         .text(function(d,i){
            return d;
         });
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://tributary.io/inlet/5817139

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what you wanted. You can do something like d3.selectAll("circle")[0][0].attributes.cx.value . Not pretty, but it works. http://tributary.io/inlet/5817382

Comment: Somewhat convoluted...I'm guessing for most documents the data is bound to the group and accessed with 'd' no matter what the element is. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. A more elegant solution might be to modify the data array before binding. something like `dataWithCoords = nodeList.map(function(d,i){return {node: d, x: coordinates[i][0], y: coordinates[i][1]};});` Then you can say `.attr("x", function(d){return d.x})` and for text `.text(function(d){return d.node;})`

Comment: exactly what I was thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with indices, this is hard to maintain and error prone. Instead of that, given your specific tree structure, use `node.previousSibling`:

```
circleGroup.append("text")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return d3.select(this.previousSibling).attr("cx");
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    return d3.select(this.previousSibling).attr("cy");
  })
```

Here is a demo using (most of) your code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var circleGroup = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("g");

circleGroup.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 20 + Math.random() * 280;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return 20 + Math.random() * 130;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return 10;
  })
  .style("opacity", 0.2);

circleGroup.append("text")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return d3.select(this.previousSibling).attr("cx");
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    return d3.select(this.previousSibling).attr("cy");
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Foo");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```